# unreadable symbols in WTK emulator

Tags: encoding, character, java-wireless-toolkit

When I run the WTK emulator from the IntelliJ Idea project all symbols are realy unreadable. I've added

```
microedition.encoding: UTF-8
microedition.locale: ru-RU
```

because all the symbols are cyrillic but it didn't help. Within the program I check these properties by System.getProperty("microedition.encoding")... and they were set but the symbols are still unreadable. How can I resolve that?
What's the most interesting fact - it's displayed well on the device, but poorly on emulator.